# How to set delay between scenarios in karate?

Tags: karate

I need to put delay between scenarios otherwise API is throwing response code of exceeding the limit (queries per second). Is it somehow possible to set some delay between scenarios? I would not like to put any javascript delay there, as there is no such thing because of single threading anyways. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate supports Java and JavaScript and since JavaScript doesn't have something like a `sleep` method, the only thing you can do is to load the `Thread` java type into JS and call [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) on that type.

This example configures a JS function to be called after every scenario:

```
Feature: A test to show how to wait between each scenario

  Background: Configure the wait function
    * configure afterScenario =
        """
      function() {
        // load java type into js engine
        var Thread = Java.type('java.lang.Thread');
        Thread.sleep(5000); // sleep for 5 Seconds
      }
      """

  Scenario: First Scenario
    * print 1

  Scenario: Second Scenario
    * print 2
```