# Waiting for a pending request to complete

Tags: karate

I’m writing tests with the karate framework

In my scenario, I have to wait for a deletion request to be made, but it takes some time (about twenty seconds).
So I would like to access the next step of my scenario only when the request is executed.
I tried this code, but this only works to integrate a delay between each scenario:

[How to set delay between scenarios in karate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957128/how-to-set-delay-between-scenarios-in-karate)

Here's the snippet where I want to do my waiting action.

```
Then waitFor(data.textareaCommentaire).delay(1000)
And clear(data.textareaCommentaire)
And clear(data.nombreOccurencesInput)
#    Wait until datas are deleted here
And waitFor(data.validerOccurenceBouton).click()
```

Apologize for my bad English

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to figure out how to use [`waitUntil()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waituntilfunction). It is up to you to find out what can be used to determine "readiness".

This is just a guess based on your question (which does not have enough useful information):

```
* def fun = function(){ return exists(data.validerOccurenceBouton) ? true : null }
* retry(10).waitUntil(fun)
```

Here we use [`exists()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#exists) to check whether the `data.validerOccurenceBouton` locator is present in the page or not. I am assuming that this will appear when the request you mention is "executed".

Also note how using [`retry(10)`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#retry-actions) will wait for up to 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for yor help @Peter Thomas. It works now. I have some difficulty using the functions in Karate, but I see it more clearly thanks to your explanation